Zio: how to use a timeout when acquiring a resource
What I want to do is try to acquire a permit from a TSemaphore, but timeout if it takes too long to acquire.
Basically something like this:
ZIO.acquireReleaseWith(semaphore.acquire.commit.timeoutFail(new TimeoutException)(acquireTimeout))(_ => doStuff())(_ => semaphore.release.commit)

However, that doesn't work, because it seems that the timeout relies on interrupting the fiber, but acquireReleaseWith doesn't allow the acquire step to be interrupted.
acquireReleaseInterruptible doesn't work, because it runs the release regardless of if the acquire succeeds, and I don't have a good out-of-band way to tell if the acquire succeeded.
And acquireReleaseInterruptibleExit doesn't really help either, because it only gives me the Exit for the whole scope, so if the doStuff() fails, then it will never release the permit.
What is the best way to have a timeout on the acquire step?

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I found something that works:
ZIO.scoped {
  for {
    _ <- semaphore.withPermitScoped.timeoutFail(new TimeoutException)(acquireTimeout)
    res <- doStuff()
  } yield res
}

Basically, move the call to the timout on an effect that does the acquireRelease, instead of the acquire action itself.
